# VS2012 cannot check in after failed (CI) build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

```
The last build of definition ****, triggered by user John, Doe, failed.
```

Obviously the last build failed and I want to check in the fix for that.
Unfortunately it won't let me check in the fix without **overriding the check in policy**.

All I could find was a [MSDN article on how to enable this check-in policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552349.aspx) (obviously it is already enabled and I have no intention in turning it off).

***Is there a proper way to check-in without overriding the check-in policy which I am not aware of?***

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to fix the build and override it at least once. After that you can continue without overriding the policy.

Comment: *shrug* ok then. Override it is. Thank you =)